# wpa_supplicant not connecting anymore to eduroam

Tags: networkmanager, 802.1x, eduroam

since a few weeks (probably after a dist-upgrade) my machine can't connect anymore to 802.1x networks.
I'm using Debian Buster with i3, but using nm-applet.
I've also tryied to connect directly with wpa_supplicant but it doesn't work either.
This is my configuration:

```
[connection]
id=eduroam
uuid=a86d2f21-990c-4a55-b7e4-933ffcffe0cd
type=wifi
permissions=user:root:;

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
ssid=eduroam

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;tkip;
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;

[802-1x]
altsubject-matches=DNS:nps1.unitn.it;DNS:nps2.unitn.it;DNS:nps3.unitn.it;
anonymous-identity=
ca-cert=/root/.cat_installer/ca.pem
eap=peap;
identity=[removed]
password=[secret]
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

This is the output of syslog:

```
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="eduroam"
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:26:0b:ac:91:d2 (SSID='eduroam' freq=2412 MHz)
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:26:0b:ac:91:d2 (SSID='eduroam' freq=2412 MHz)
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: Associated with 00:26:0b:ac:91:d2
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=IT
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25 -> NAK
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=21
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 21 (TTLS) selected
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:26:0b:ac:91:d2 reason=4 locally_generated=1
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 54:75:d0:3f:4d:2d (SSID='eduroam' freq=5200 MHz)
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 54:75:d0:3f:4d:2d (SSID='eduroam' freq=5200 MHz)
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: Associated with 54:75:d0:3f:4d:2d
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=IT
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25 -> NAK
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=21
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 21 (TTLS) selected
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/CN=eduradius-dr-2018' hash=86fdb85978a8d3c9ba28e40f1f10415d49c0a595b8752556906d37ac9d1884fc
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/CN=eduradius-dr-2018' hash=86fdb85978a8d3c9ba28e40f1f10415d49c0a595b8752556906d37ac9d1884fc
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: Authentication with 54:75:d0:3f:4d:2d timed out.
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=54:75:d0:3f:4d:2d reason=3 locally_generated=1
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="eduroam" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=AUTH_FAILED
wpa_supplicant[1075]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
```

Apart from waiting for an update what could I do?

Update, dmseg -wL output:

```
[72642.755504] wlan0: authenticate with 54:75:d0:3f:4d:22
[72642.757856] wlan0: send auth to 54:75:d0:3f:4d:22 (try 1/3)
[72642.761033] wlan0: authenticated
[72642.763678] wlan0: associate with 54:75:d0:3f:4d:22 (try 1/3)
[72642.766431] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 54:75:d0:3f:4d:22 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[72642.768628] wlan0: associated
[72642.863828] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 17 dBm as advertised by 54:75:d0:3f:4d:22
[72647.757757] wlan0: deauthenticated from 54:75:d0:3f:4d:22 (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

UPDATE:
Seems that' the problem is wpa_supplicant 2.6
I solved the problem by downgrading to 2.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320587/network-manager-cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-eap e.g. your upgrade might be using a version of TLS that they do not support. I would talk with the university helpdesk, they might be aware of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the bug by downgrading wpasupplicant from version 2.6 to version 2.4

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem on my university. It turned out that the access points received a firmware update which broke support for certain WIFI adapters.

Since the reason for the failing connection is "AUTH_FAILED" and not something like "WRONG_KEY" I would ask the administrator of your eduroam network if he knows about some incompatibility.

In parallel you could check whether the kernel log contains some information about problems with your WIFI adapter's firmware. Open a terminal and watch the output of `dmesg -wL` while trying to connect to the network. If you find something fishy please post it here, maybe we can find out what's wrong.

Comment: I don't see any strange behaviour in dmesg

Comment: In that case I don't see an obvious why you should get no connection. I would check with the support desk of you university / institute.

Comment: The university technician checked the log and told me that the password is incorrect. Obvsly the pwd in my configuration file is correct, so what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following:

```
    systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
    systemctl list-units | grep -iE '(net|dhcp|wpa|conn|wicd)'
```

Ensure to stop and deactivate all network managing services and try a manual connection:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Manual_setup

This may also be helpful:

You may need to change ath5k to what ever module your wifi card uses same for the config file.

```
    echo "options ath5k nohwcrypt=Y" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf
    sudo iw reg set GB
```

Information which was found here:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=231904

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2279555

Comment: should i do it even if i my module is  iwlwifi?

Comment: Check this page out: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Iwlwifi  Check the Testing section...