# Troubleshooting "DEAUTH_LEAVING" error when connecting to WPA2-Enterprise network after Linux upgrade

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, wpa2-eap

I'm not able to solve this error

```
[  666.695694] wlan0: deauthenticating from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

I obtain the error only when I'm trying to connect to a WPA2-Enterprise network (`EAP-MSCHAP2`). Other connections work well without any error.

This error has been obtained after a Linux upgrade, currently I'm using

```
Linux root 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2kali1 (2018-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Lurking I've seen a possible cause to this problem: the TLSv1.2 support has been disabled. I've seen several solutions with `wpa_supplicant`, but I'm using `NetworkManager`. I've also tried to configure `wpa_supplicant` without any result.

What can I do?

Comment: Ummm......network manager is just a front-end for wpa_supplicant.  Debian even took the words right out of my mouth: "NetworkManager is also a front-end for wpa_supplicant."  https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant

Comment: Ok, but I don't have a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file and all my network configurations are in in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. All "workarounds" found are based on a modification of `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I've understood the problem but I'm not able to find a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["aborting authentication by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH\_LEAVING)" when trying to connect to wifi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386925/aborting-authentication-by-local-choice-reason-3-deauth-leaving-when-trying)

Comment: Not a duplicate: I don't have an interface with a long name. My interface is the standard `wlan0`

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same problem. 
[wpa_supplicant not connecting anymore to eduroam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482727/wpa-supplicant-not-connecting-anymore-to-eduroam/482790?noredirect=1#comment884178_482790)

We should try to figure out what package update introduced this bug and either revert it to the previous version or fix it.

Update:
I found that the 25th of november libssl got updated in debian testing/unstable to version  1.1.1a-1.
wpasupplicant, instead, hasn't been updated since August.

I tried to downgrade both and actually the problematic one is wpasupplicant.
Try to install the older version by:

`sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant=2:2.4-1+deb9u2`

then mark it hold with:

`sudo  apt-mark hold wpasupplicant`